# How to handle deserialization of mixed-type values in TOML (string/integer)?

Tags: rust, deserialization, serde, toml

When deserializing a TOML file, how can I instruct the deserializer to treat a value for a specific key as a string, regardless of whether it appears to be an integer?

#### Background

I want to parse a TOML file where the value of `count` could be either an integer or a string:

```ini
count = 3
# or count = -1
# or count = "all"
```

Valid values for `count` (in the TOML file) should be `-1..i32::MAX`, or `"all"`. When deserializing the value, `"all"` should be interpreted as `-1`.

#### The Problem

This is my code, using a custom deserializer, and it pretty much works ...

```rust
use serde::{de::Error, Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ConfigFileOpts {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "ds_i32_or_string")]
    count: i32,
}

fn ds_i32_or_string<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<i32, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let res = String::deserialize(deserializer);
    match res {
        Ok(s) => match s.parse::<i32>() {
            Ok(n) if n >= -1 => Ok(n),
            _ => match s.trim().to_lowercase().as_str() {
                "all" => Ok(-1),
                _ => Err(D::Error::custom("Value must be >= -1 or 'all'.")),
            },
        },
        Err(e) => Err(e),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cfg_opts: ConfigFileOpts = toml::from_str("count = 3").unwrap();
    println!("deserialized count: {:?}", cfg_opts.count);
}
```

... *however*, it only works when integer values are written as strings, i.e. `count = "3"` instead of `count = 3`. When `count` is written as `count = 3` I'm getting the following error message:

```
TomlError {
  message: "invalid type: integer `3`, expected a string",
  original: Some("count = 3"),
  keys: ["count"],
  span: Some(8..9)
}
```

Currently, the deserializer is not called for values that "look like" integers. Is there a way to ensure my deserializer is invoked for both integer and string values? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: _"Currently, the deserializer is not called for values that "look like" integers."_ Are you sure about that? I'd expect it to be called but for `String::deserialize()` to be returning `Err`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your original design, you can use derive of serde of an enum to simplify the code for you:

```rust
use serde::{de::Error, Deserialize, Deserializer};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ConfigFileOpts {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "ds_i32_or_string")]
    count: i32,
}

fn ds_i32_or_string<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<i32, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    #[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum Count {
        S(String),
        I(i32),
    }

    let count = Count::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    match count {
        Count::S(s) => {
            if s.trim().to_lowercase().as_str() == "all" {
                Ok(-1)
            } else {
                Err(D::Error::custom("Value must be >= -1 or 'all'."))
            }
        }
        Count::I(n) => {
            if n >= -1 {
                Ok(n)
            } else {
                Err(D::Error::custom("Value must be >= -1"))
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cfg_opts: ConfigFileOpts = toml::from_str("count = 42").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(42, cfg_opts.count);

    let cfg_opts: ConfigFileOpts = toml::from_str("count = \"all\"").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(-1, cfg_opts.count);

    let cfg_opts: ConfigFileOpts = toml::from_str("count = -1").unwrap();
    assert_eq!(-1, cfg_opts.count);

    let ret: Result<ConfigFileOpts, _> = toml::from_str("count = -42");
    assert!(ret.is_err());
}
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution – thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can stop implementing custom deserializers with the help of [serde_with](https://docs.rs/serde_with/latest/serde_with/guide/serde_as_transformations/index.html#pick-first-successful-deserialization) crate:

```rust
use serde_with::{PickFirst, DisplayFromStr};

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct ConfigFileOpts {
    #[serde_as(as = "PickFirst<(_, DisplayFromStr)>")]
    count: i32,
}
```

Though, if you wonder how this helper could be implemented by hand, there are [two options](https://serde.rs/impl-deserialize.html):

1. Call `toml::Deserializer::deserialize_any` method, and match the resulting `Value` against its [definition](https://docs.rs/toml/latest/toml/enum.Value.html).
2. Try `deserialize_i32`, on error try `deserialize_str` (which is equivalent to `String::deserialize`).

Comment: Thank you, @xamgore. I looked into `toml::Deserializer::deserialize_any` but couldn't figure out how to work it since the deserializer that's passed to the value parser seems to be a `serde::Deserializer`. I'm very new to Rust, so there might be a few things I'm not grokking.